# Integrate Spring MVC with legacy JAX-RS application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jax-rs, jetty

I have a legacy application, using JAX-RS for REST. Now i want to integrate Spring MVC but i cant rewrite all the old code. So, is it possible to use in the same time JAX-RS with Spring MVC? I mean, the old code will stay as it is for the moment and new controllers will use Spring MVC. 
I am using Jetty as web server.

web.xml:

```xml
     <servlet>
             <servlet-name>Restlet</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>com.anue.webapi.RestletServlet</servlet-class>
             <init-param>
                     <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
                     <param-value>com.anue.webapi.RestletWebApiApplication</param-value>
             </init-param>
     </servlet>


<filter>
    <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>mimeTypes</param-name>
        <param-value>text/html,text/plain,text/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/css,application/javascript,application/json,image/svg+xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>GzipFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CacheSettingsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.netoptics.server.CacheSettingsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CacheSettingsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>



<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Restlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: In real-world applications, it will usually be simpler to write a separate Spring (Boot) application and use your load balancer or other request router to direct requests appropriately.

Comment: Noticed something unrelated in your posted XML - [`GzipFilter` - that's been deprecated in Jetty 9.0.0](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/GzipFilter.java#L45) for being incompatible with Servlet 3.1 Async I/O and replaced with `GzipHandler` (added at server level, not webapp).   Note that some components at Spring have made this change already.